# How can I write and read JSON strings to Google Cloud buckets using JavaScript from my web app?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I have spent most of today poking around Google's site looking for information about Javascript APIs to do this with no success. Everything seems to be based on an app running on the host (cloud functions?). Doesn't Google have an equivalent to Amazon's JavaScript API for Amazon S3? See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-examples.html

I have an app where I currently use Firebase to read and write application data as JSON strings to the RealTime DataBase. Now I want to do the same thing but using buckets. I've gone through the tutorial about using the console tools to upload media files, but there is nothing about web client JS tools for string data. I set up a new project just for this new project, created a bucket and have the Firebase config parameters. I would like to see some example code showing the format of the API calls to use. I found some examples of hosting static web pages with http calls to download them, but the files were uploaded from the console, not by an API. Can anyone give me a reference to tutorials or examples for accessing buckets for string data from a browser with JS? Or is this not possible?

Comment: From your web app running in the browser or from Node.js running on a web server? Two similar but very different environments.

Comment: One can access GCS (Google Cloud Storage) from any environment that allows REST calls and this would include JS in a browser.  Here is an API .. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/get ... and here is an overview page https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/

Comment: @Kolban  Yes that's what I was looking for. I couldn't find it. I am storing text strings (JSON) of JS objects that I will then Get and modify. Then I want to update the stored bucket object (string). It looks like I have to Delete and Insert to accomplish this, correct? This is essentially a database of time series price data for stocks stored by symbol name, to be updated with new daily price data.